# How to replace string pattern using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have string pattern like following

abcd(100 efgh)

I would like to change string pattern above into following using sed.

ab(100)

abcd and efgh is fixed string but the number(here is 100) is not fixed, can be any number. 
Does anyone have some idea about it and could you give some advice? 
I am always thankful for sharing.

Comment: use capture groups and backreferences - see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions ..  you'd get help with code you tried but didn't work.. don't expect solutions to be given freely

Answer (score 0):

Use a capture group to remember the number, use a character class to match it:

```
echo 'abcd(100 efgh)' | sed 's/abcd(\([0-9]\+\) efgh)/ab(\1)/'
```

(non-gnu seds might not have `+`, use `[0-9][0-9]*` instead.